# The latter had never been "underdrawn"

Tags: literature

Source : *Wuthering Heights*, by Emily Bronte.

Extract:

> One end, indeed, reflected splendidly both light and heat from ranks of immense pewter dishes, interspersed with silver jugs and tankards, towering row after row, on a vast oak dresser, to the very roof.The latter had never been **under-drawn**: its entire anatomy lay bare to an inquiring eye, except where a frame of wood laden with oatcakes and clusters of legs of beef, mutton, and ham, concealed it.

What does the word "under-drawn" mean in this context?

Comment: You mean "under-drawn".

Comment: I think the following clause explains the meaning somewhat

Answer (score 4):

It should be quite clear from the context, the passage is talking at that point about the roof and tells you that because it has never been 'under-drawn' you can see its whole structure. Therefore there is no ceiling, you can see the rafters.

> [Underdraw](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/underdrawn) . to line the underside of (a structure, as a floor)
> with plasterwork, boarding, or the like.              
> Dictionary.com

Where the structure is described as being concealed, it is concealed by

> a frame of wood laden with oatcakes and clusters of legs of beef,
> mutton, and ham

It means [something akin to this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:PlasMawrKitchen.jpg#/media/File:PlasMawrKitchen.jpg), if likely not quite so grand.
[image: Kitchen of Plas_Mawr]

a version is shown in this image which is [a simple stick suspended from the beams](http://l7.alamy.com/zooms/4aa5e9dc9a374920bb43128fbe721052/interior-of-the-kitchen-at-elizabeth-farm-an-historical-homestead-hege05.jpg),
[image: Kitchen of an Elizabethan farm]but shown how the things stored on it (to keep them away from vermin) could be bulky and stop you seeing the roof beyond.

Comment: Then how come " the frame of wood laden with..." conceal it? I don't get the picture.

Comment: @user211390 The exception relates to "entire anatomy lay bare" - that is, people can see the bottom of the roof in its entirety except where things block their line of sight.

Comment: @user211390 I've edited the answer to provide a link to an image you may find helpful.

Comment: If you aren't already familiar with the term, I don't think context helps that much. Many people would read "the latter" to refer to the oak dresser, not the roof, because of it's weak position buried in a locative prepositional phrase. I knew what it meant and still found the sentence awkward.

Comment: @PhilSweet I don't see it that way, obviously :) Here is how I approached the passage, not knowing previously what under-drawn meant. Read through, get to reference of 'latter', check back to order things introduced, assume roof, read rest. Pause and think, picturing a wooden frame with stuff hanging on it. Conjecture that since the frame blocks structure that would be blocked if roof under-drawn that underdrawing means blocking off the roof structure. Look-up to verify in order to post answer. I said one should be able to go from context because that's what I did.

Comment: @Spagirl, Is that not a workable definition of an awkward sentence? I don't know why, but when I encounter *latter*, I'm looking for the last element of some parallel list of items, and I tend to exclude from consideration peripheral nouns. Consider " ... a cat on the sill and a dog on the porch. The latter ... ." Latter refers to dog, yes?

Comment: @PhilSweet In a sentence where you have clear items like dog and cat yes, but what would you designate 'former' in the quoted text if the dresser is 'latter'? I find the Brontes, and indeed any historic writers quite a slow read anyway as fashions in sentence structure and length change with time. What I did was go to an online text so that I was looking at the quote in context (often people snip out crucial context) so was aware that the longer passage was concerned with describing the interior of a house. Perhaps that coloured my view of the relative importance of 'roof'.

Comment: @Spagirl That makes sense. I suspect I misunderstood the OPs 'context' in my earlier comment. The passage was confusing to me as a stand-alone sentence.

Comment: @Phil I didn’t know the word _underdraw_ and had no idea what it meant, but I immediately understood (more or less) what it was supposed to convey here just from the context.